# Sending multiple messages on Facebook when the user name is "Facebook User"?

Tags: facebook

Last week, I had a message request on Facebook from someone (he or she is harassing me and my fiance). The user appear as "Facebook User". I guess this means that he/she has deleted their profile after sending this message. The strange thing is that I had another message in the same chat window today from this person, also with the name "Facebook User". I also know that you cannot name a profile as "Facebook User".

How is that possible, or how could someone send messages this way?

Comment: This is a question for Facebook support

Comment: @AndrolGenhald I  am asking from a security/anonymity/technical  perspective , not trying to find out who is that person.

Comment: Maybe when asked for their name, they just entered "Facebook User"?

Comment: @GOmar "how is this possible" requires that we know how their chat function is coded

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, that's strange. Initially I thought that they sent you a message, blocked you, unblocked you, sent you a message, and then blocked you again. The reason this explanation doesn't work is because when someone blocks you, their name is still visible; you won't see them as "Facebook User," which is what appears when someone *permanently deletes their account.* When someone *deactivates* their account, their name is still visible. Unfortunately, I don't know how they could be doing this, assuming it is true that someone can't create a Facebook profile with the name "Facebook User." Here's what you can do in the meantime.

**DOCUMENT EVERYTHING!** Take screenshots *of your entire browser,* messages included, because there may be some valuable information in the URL. Download a copy of your data (instructions on how to do that [here](https://www.facebook.com/help/302796099745838)) so you have an archive of the messages they've sent you. Tell your partner to do the same.

**Contact Facebook.** Reach out to support and bring this to their attention. Since you can't venture to their profile, try finding a report feature within the message window. You should see a gear or Actions button that presents you with more options. See if there's a block user or report function in there.

**Lock down your profiles.** You can restrict who can send you messages: everyone, friends of friends, friends only, etc. Instructions on that [here](http://www.healthypasswords.com/content.Healthy_Passwords_How_To_Restrict_Messages_to_Only_Friends.html). I would recommend using this feature, as it should prevent this person from subsequent trolling. *Do not accept friend requests from people you do not know.*

Finally, read the contents of your messages and think if it could be someone that you and/or your partner know.

Hopefully these measures will put an end to this creep...

**Update:** It seems to be possible to create a profile called "Facebook User." I did a search on Facebook of such profiles and here are the [results](https://www.facebook.com/search/top/?q=facebook%20user). OP, explore the message window and see if you can access this person's profile. There should be a way to get to it through messages, and their Facebook user ID should be in the URL when you're looking at the conversation history with this person.

Comment: You need to provide some other proof of being able to create a profile called "Facebook User" - your link returns nothing for me. Secondly, this does not answer the question at all. When told to contact FB support, the OP rejected the suggestion.

Comment: That's weird, the link displays results for me. I would suggest conducting a search on Facebook yourself, then. 

It absolutely answers the question, because the point of contention here is whether or not someone can create a Facebook account called "Facebook User." He's operating under the assumption (and so was I in my response) that such a profile cannot be created. 

I provided evidence to the contrary and steps he should take to secure his account, whether his assumption is correct or incorrect. I'm not sure why you think my reply is off base.

Comment: Can you describe what the search results in for you? What do you see?

Comment: The question is off-base because how to secure the account is not the question

Comment: The list of results I get features profiles, groups, and pages titled "Facebook User" and its variants, for example: "Facèbook Usêr." This [page](https://www.facebook.com/Facebook-User-131756870193370/) is one of the results that came up. Can you see it?

Comment: Yes, I get Pages, and Groups, but no *users*. Maybe I'm missing something but can a Page or a Group that you are not part of start a chat with you?

Comment: I don't have a Facebook, so the search results are limited for me. I get about ten results and I stand corrected: none of them are users/personal profiles. Some of them are pages. Pages and groups can send messages to users and vice versa.

Comment: Thank you for the tips, however the search results are as you said for groups / pages only not USERS .. still no one figures out what how can someone send messages this way

Comment: I am suggesting that the sender is using a thirdparty software/website to send the message not a facebook  account , but not sure if this even possible ?